# How to get details from logged user

Tags: angular, typescript, jwt

i want to retrieve logged user informations from local storage so i can greet the user after his authentication to the the app.

```
login(user){
    localStorage.setItem('currentUser',  JSON.stringify(user));
    return this.http.post(this.host+"/login",user, {observe:'response'});
}


export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  currentUser:User;

  constructor(public authenticationService:AuthenticationService) {
    this.currentUser= JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser'));
    console.log(this.currentUser);
}
```

Here i call the user from local storage but it doesn't work. Can you help me with that?

```
<div class="alert alert-dark" role="alert">
    <h2>Welcome {{currentUser.firstName}} !!</h2>
</div>
```

Comment: This should be JSON.stringify instead of `login(user){
    localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.parse(user));` and there is a typo in `getItem('currentUer')` instead of `currentUser`

Answer (score 0):

At this line:

```
this.currentUser = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUer'));
```

you are getting `currentUer` not `currentUser`.

In the devtools are you viewing that key?

Comment: @Suryan Thank you for you answers i did correct my code above, but currentUser returns just the username and the password of the user and not the other fields like firstName, so i must use another function to retrieve the user with all fields.